# RMI Load Test Tool?

Tags: java, testing, jakarta-ee, rmi, load-testing

I am looking for an opensource/free load testing tool to test applications over RMI.

I only know the JMeter plugin "JMeter RMI Sampler", but I am looking for another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/), a Java Load Testing Framework.
The Grinder 3 is both open-source and [supports RMI protocol](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/features.html#Standards):

> The Grinder can be used to test RPC and MOM based systems using
>   protocols such as IIOP, **RMI/IIOP, RMI/JRMP**, and JMS.